# passing internet thru Linux machine

Tags: linux, windows, networking, security

recently, I have been running into a lot of DDoS attacks while playing some online games.

in an attempt too stop these attacks, I plan too have my secondary Linux machine act as a passthrough in which internet traffic can be filtered before being received by my windows machine.

I plan on running iptables on said Linux machine, which I have already acquired from a trusted source.

any idea if this is even possible? if this is, it would be appreciated if I could be sent links for required resources such as drivers and programs.

while I understand there are probably better ways too circumvent these attacks, this is something I've wanted too experiment with for a while, so I figure id sate my curiosity in the process.

also, id like too apologize in advance if a lot of my IT Jargon is messed up, I'm not a professional in this field and I'm making a lot of inferences.

[image]

Comment: It seems to me to be a whole lot easier to get a good router that stops such attacks. My router does that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're suffering from DDoS attacks, your architecture isn't going to help.

The DDoS could be doing two things:

- It clogs up your internet connection. Your router and the Linux box are behind the internet connection (as seen from the internet), so the traffic is  already hitting a bottleneck before having a chance to filter.
- It clogs up your router. Again, using the reasoning above, the traffic is already hitting the bottleneck before there is a chance to filter.

---

To strictly answer your question: Yes, you can do this. Look up any tutorial on the web on how to create a Linux router. Given your apparent skill level with Linux, it might be easier to go with a distribution made for that particular purpose, like PFSense (not strictly Linux, but BSD) or OpenWRT. That will do exactly what you asked for (but not likely what you want).

Comment: I see, that makes sense. it turns out whoever the attacker is is using what looks too be his home ip, so i just notified his isp of what his happening. the attacks have stopped now, thanks for the help